# C# SqlCommand Inserting Null Values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a CSV file that has about 4 million rows of clean data in it, and I need to import it into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I tried to do this via TSQL only, SSIS, and few other methods, but in the end I always encountered the same problem, each row has a 2,000+ columns. SQL server had a problem with reading that many columns in a CSV file.

So, I ended up writing a little C# console program to parse the csv file and do all the work to break out the 2,000+ columns into their relational tables in my database. Everything is working great, but with the CSV file having 4 million rows, efficiency is key here.

All that said, here is the problem I am having, and can't for the life me figure out. I am using the old SqlCommand class to do bulk inserts. I can't figure out how to get a null value into the db. For instance, take this line

```
var PreparedCommand = "insert into person_modeling_info (person_id, modeling_info,     response) values "; 

PreparedCommand += "( " + info[0] + ",'" + info[1] + "'," + (item2.Value == "" ? "'NULL'" : "'"+item2.Value+"'") + "),";
```

I am not worried about SQL injection, as I am 100% sure that the data is clean. I know I can insert null using parameters, but parameters are slower as I have to insert one record at a time vs. doing a bulk insert like 
`insert into table (values), (values), (values)`

When I perform the insert using concatenation, it gets inserted into the database as an empty string.

If any one has an ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _I am not worried about SQL injection_ You should my friend, you should..

Comment: Why, it's moving data from one system in house to another in house.

Comment: `NULL` without quotes should do. Of course, injection issue stands as is.

Comment: `"'NULL'"` produces the string NULL, remove the single quotes as its a DB keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `item2.Value` isn't already == null? Have you tried:

```
PreparedCommand += "( " + info[0] + ",'" + info[1] + "'," + (item2.Value == null ? "'NULL'" : "'"+item2.Value+"'") + "),";
```

Comment: I'd suggest use of `String.IsNullOrEmpty` rather than a simple null check (given that what you are doing is changing the behaviour of empty strings) but yes, this seems like a plausible explanation.

Comment: @Chris: in a database, like in C#, `null` and `''` are different.

Comment: @Andomar: Yes, they are but the user is currently treating an empty string the same as null so  I would be inclined to keep that behaviour while also checking for null rather than change the existing behaviour without explicitly flagging it up. If the user has problems with empty strings going in as null as well then I'm sure he would have saaid.

Answer (score 1):

You should try in this way:

you have to remove single quote from the `'NULL'`, also add check for `item2.Value` is null or empty.

```
var PreparedCommand = "insert into person_modeling_info (person_id, modeling_info,     response) values "; 

    PreparedCommand += "( " + info[0] + ",'" + info[1] + "'," + ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(item2.Value)==true?  "NULL" : "'"+item2.Value+"'") + "),";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make your insert columns conditional using the same idea:

```
var PreparedCommand = "insert into person_modeling_info (person_id, modeling_info" + (item2.Value == "" ? "" : ",response") + ") values "; 

PreparedCommand += "( " + info[0] + ",'" + info[1] + "'" + (item2.Value == "" ? "" : ",'"+item2.Value+"'") + "),";
```

Preferably, you'd want to use SQL Parameters and use DbNull.Value

Comment: Right, I tried that initially, but it was slower as doing that required me to insert each row individually. When I moved to *shudder* string concatenation with bulk inserting, it shaved about 40 seconds off run time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and assign [`DbNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Really, no excuses. On a public forum like this posting SQL injection code is an offense. Some innocent idiot will copy/paste it 2 years later...

Of course, moving **efficiently** 4M rows from CSV is really a question about [bcp.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx) or, at worst, [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I recommend reading the [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and learn about [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: It's not an offense, and you are wrong. I am not an idiot, and I am very aware that it is SQL injection vulnerable. However, I am not worried about that as this program is doing nothing more than moving CLEAN data from an in house flat file into a relational database.