# How to Insert a Null Value to a column if there is not value to that column?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am inserting data from a text file into a tables. In that text file, each line will have either 7 values or 8 values.

In DB I've changed table so it has 8 columns.

If the file comes with 7 values, I need to handle it to add 8:th value as NULL. How can I add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# SqlCommand Inserting Null Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951728/c-sharp-sqlcommand-inserting-null-values)

Comment: By sending DBNull.Value to DB?
Provide more information about what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

null (used in programming) is different from the Database value null.
One possible solution:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueToAdd))
 {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", DBNull.Value);
 }
 else
 { 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add", ValueToAdd); 
 }
```